# Model selection for classification with random train/test sets

Tags: machine-learning, classification, training-data

I'm working with an extremelly **unbalanced and heterogeneous** multiclass `{K = 16}` database for research, with a small `N ~= 250`. For some labels the database has a sufficient amount of examples for supervised machine learning, but for others I have almost none. I'm also not in a position to expand my database for a number of reasons.

As a first approach I divided my database into training (80%) and test (20%) sets in a **stratified** way. On top of that, I applied several classification algorithms that provide some results. I applied this procedure over **500 stratified train/test sets** ([as each stratified sampling takes individuals randomly within each stratum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling)), hoping to select an algorithm (model) that performed acceptably.

Because of my database, depending on the specific examples that are part of the train set, the performance on the test set varies greatly. I'm dealing with runs that have as high (for my application) as 82% accuracy and runs that have as low as 40%. The median over all runs is around 67% accuracy.

When facing this situation, I'm unsure on what is the standard procedure (if there is any) when selecting the best performing model. My rationale is that the 90% model may generalize better because the specific examples selected in the training set are be richer so that the test set is better classified. However, I'm fully aware of the possibility of the test set being composed of *"simpler"* cases that are easier to classify or the train set comprising all hard-to-classify cases.

Is there any **standard procedure** to select the **best performing model** considering that the distribution of examples in my train/test sets cause the results to vary greatly? Am I making a conceptual mistake somewhere? Do practitioners usually select the **best performing model** without any **further exploration**?

I don't like the idea of using the mean/median accuracy, as obviously some models generalize better than others, but I'm by no means an expert in the field.

Confusion matrix of the predicted label on the test set of one of the best cases:

[image: Confusion Matrix of one of the runs]

Confusion matrix of the predicted label on the test set of one of the worst cases:

[image: Confusion matrix of another run]

**They both use the same algorithm and parameters**.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "random and stratified"? Splits that are at the same time random *and* stratified, or some splits being random while others being stratified?

Comment: You are right, as stratified sampling applies simple sampling in each stratum. I'll modify the question in a moment.

Comment: In addition to my answer, I want to remark that such a question might be better off on the [Stats Stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), since this is not directly related to programming, and their experts could be much more knowledgable in these areas than the *programming* experts on SO.

Answer (score 1):

### Good Accuracy =/= Good Model

I want to firstly point out that a good accuracy on your test set *need not* equal a good model in general! This has (in your case) mainly to do with your extremely skewed distribution of samples.
Especially when doing a stratified split, and having one class dominatingly represented, you will likely get good results by simply predicting this one class over and over again.

A good way to see if this is happening is to look at a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) (better picture [here](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/wp-content/uploads/2015-11-30-Data-Preparation-The-balancing-act/Figure_2_logreg_11_classes_confusion_matrix.jpeg)) of your predictions. 
If there is one class that seems to confuse other classes as well, that is an indicator for a bad model. I would argue that in your case it would be generally very hard to find a good model unless you do actively try to balance your classes more during training.

### Use the power of Ensembles

Another idea is indeed to use ensembling over multiple models (in your case resulting from different splits), since it is assumed to [generalize better](https://erikbern.com/2014/04/24/the-power-of-ensembles.html). 
Even if you might sacrifice a lot of accuracy on paper, I would bet that a confusion matrix of an ensemble is likely to look much better than the one of a single "high accuracy" model. Especially if you disregard the models that perform extremely poor (make sure that, again, the "poor" performance comes from an actual bad performance, and not just an unlucky split), I can see a very good generalization.

### Try k-fold Cross-Validation

Another common technique is k-fold cross-validation. Instead of performing your evaluation on a single 80/20 split, you essentially divide your data in k equally large sets, and then always train on k-1 sets, while evaluating on the other set. You then not only get a feeling whether your split was reasonable (you usually get all the results for different splits in k-fold CV implementations, like the one from [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)), but you also get an *overall score* that tells you the average of all folds.
Note that 5-fold CV would equal a split into 5 20% sets, so essentially what you are doing now, plus the "shuffling part".
CV is also a good way to deal with little training data, in settings where you have imbalanced classes, or where you generally want to make sure your model actually performs well.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your interest in my problem. The thing with my dataset is that I'm using 10-fold cross-validation in my training data already, but the wildly different results I'm obtaining are due to the specific examples that comprise the train and test set. That is, using the same algorithm with the same cross-validation and everything twice produces wildly different results, as the inclusion of one example or another in the train/test sets affects the output wildly. The different models themselves offer more or less the same results (1-2% difference) over the same training data X.